# How can I preserve the commas in the text when they're also delimiters when reading csv in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

So csv file looks like this:

```
|  A |  B  |  C     |
 ---- ----- --------
  1  |  2 | Hello123,hi
```

so in plain text a row is `1,2,Hello123,hi`

I've seen similar questions on stack overflow with no clear solutions. I cannot alter the csv file. Is there anything I can incorporate in these methods? Could I somehow split on only the first 2 commas?

```
df = pd.read_csv()
```

```
df.to_sql
```

Comment: If your row looks like `1,2,Hello,hi` and it is supposed to hold 3 values, then your csv is broken. The problem lies with whatever created a broken csv file.

Comment: Your CSV does not look like that if the first row looks like that

Comment: Hey, it was just a typo. I’m on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to read the file one line at a time, building an array or list of list, but pythons split function can do it:

```
>>> t="1,2,hello, Joe"
>>> t.split(',',2)
['1', '2', 'hello, Joe']
```